# User interface for Spring Roo

Tags: java, gwt, spring-roo, tiles

I am developing an application using Spring Roo. I need to decide the front end for my application.
Can anybody please give a comparison of Apache Tiles vs GWT for Spring Roo front end?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Tiles is a template framework.  Where as GWT if toolkit where you have plenty of widgets and containers.  So GWT is the best option for UI development with Spring Roo combination.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not in your question but did you give a chance to Vaadin instead of GWT? The Vaadin plugin for Roo allows you to create an app with a few commands. Vaadin sits on top of GWT and manages much of the client-server communication in the components for you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [tag]rui and the spring roo has vaadin plugin https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Spring%20Roo%20Plugin.